# Injection of a stateless EJB into JSFmanaged bean causes NullPointer ex in WAS 8.5

Tags: jsf, ejb, websphere, code-injection

A Java EE 6 Project using JSF 2.x mojarra implementation (both 2.0 and 2.1 tested) where session beans are injected via @EJB annotations into JSF managed beans fails in Websphere Application Server 8.5 whereas it functions on Glassfish 3.x (tested on GF 3.0 & 3.1 respectively) as it is:

The coding approach is like below:

**SomeEJBFacade.java**

```
@Stateless
public class SomeEJBFacade() {

     public String testMethod() {
        return "testing 1 2 3";
     }

}
```

**TestBean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements java.io.Serializable {
    @EJB SomeEJBFacade facade;

    public String getTestStr() {
        return facade.testMethod();
    }
}
```

JSF facelet fragment:

```
<h:outputText value="#{testBean.testStr}" />
```

the above causes a **Null Pointer Exception** from TestBean's *testStr()* method.

Likewise any JPA transactional method throws null pointer exceptions at
similar points.

Comment: This looks like it should work. You might have found a product defect, so I would suggest opening a PMR with IBM.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that GlassFishs and WebSpheres classloader do work in a differnt way. You have to add the ejb modul as a dependency in the Web-projects META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Class-Path: EnappDaemonEJB.jar
```

Where as 'EnappDaemonEJB.jar' is the name of generated jar/EJB artefact - or in other words, the name of my EJB-project is 'EnappDaemonEJB'.

Link: [WebSphere Infocenter - see Procedure point 2](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tweb_troubleshoot_cdi.html)

Comment: I've been told by a Websphere specialist that WAS does not support dependency injection in Mojarra impelemntation, and the use of Apache MyFaces is enforced for DI within WAS.

Comment: Well (at)EJB is JEE CDI standard and (at)ManagedBean is JSF... But in fact mojarra overwrites the injection engine: https://www.java.net//node/701374. Tried it and on WAS 8.5.0.2 with Mojarra 2.0.3 injection does not work neither with (at)EJB nor with (at)Inject... So my answer is wrong! Sorry for that...

Comment: In the case of using Mojarra 2.x on WAS, it does not work with @Named annotated controller beans either.